# How to map values based on the parent element attribute value

Tags: dataweave

Input, can have n number of entities and multiple values under attbribute:
Here is basic example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entityset>
    <entity name="dog">
        <attribute code="app">
            <value>my application</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute code="1code">
            <value>dog1value</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute code="">
            <value>dog2value</value>
        </attribute>
    </entity>
    <entity name="cat">
        <attribute code="app">
            <value>my cat application</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute code="1code">
            <value>cat1value</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute code="2code">
            <value>cat2value</value>
        </attribute>
    </entity>
</entityset>
```

My DW for starters:

```
{
    insert: payload.entityset.*entity map {
        id: $.@name,
        name: $.attribute.value when $.attribute.@code=='1code' otherwise '',
        owner: $.attribute.value when payload.entityset.entity.attribute.@code=='2code' otherwise ''    

    }
```

}

Desired output:

```
<insert>
   <record>
       <id>dog</id>
       <name>dog1value</name>
       <owner>dogvalue2</owner>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>cat</id>
        <name>cat1value</name>
        <owner>cat2value<owner>
    </record>
 </insert>
```

What i'm not able to figure out is how to make a condition
 if attribute.@code=="1code" then map that attributa.value to . and code2 attributes to owner.
I'm reading input from xml file. When I try to introduce "map" then i get always an error:

Exception stack is:
1. Cannot coerce a :array to a :object (com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.exception.UnsupportedTypeCoercionException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.ObjectTypeCoercionValue:31 (null)
2. Exception while executing: 
    insert: payload.entityset.*entity map {
                              ^
Cannot coerce a :array to a :object (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler:166 (null)

Answer (score 0):

The result of the * selector is an array so you can not map it as an object. Also when going down in the levelsof objects is easy to lose sight of the current level. This script achieves the expected result:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    insert: payload.entityset.*entity mapObject {
        record: {
            id: $.@name,
            name: (($.*attribute  filter ($.@code=='1code')) map ($.value))[0] default '',
            owner: (($.*attribute  filter ($.@code=='2code')) map ($.value))[0] default ''
        }
}
```